# Cakephp 3.x : how to structure complexe authorisation with multiple roles

Tags: php, cakephp, authorization, structure, cakephp-3.x

I'm currently working in a big project with CakePHP3.x and I'm trying to have a code as clean as possible. You can see the visual structure of the database on the first picture:

[image: database structure]

One user has multiple roles. With the Auth component and the prefix system, I managed to secure most of the pages without too much trouble. However, on some parts of the website, the problem is more complex.

Here a quick exemple of what special users can do:

```
Local Manager (secured by the prefix /local)
-- Can edit only his own local group

Regional Manager (secured by the prefix /region)
-- Can edit every local groups included in his region (with /local)
-- Can edit his own region (with /region)

National Manager (secured by the prefix /national)
-- Can edit every region in his own zone (with /region)
```

There is legacy system like : Local < Regional < National.

On the url "local/edit/:id" I had to do something like that witch is really not something that I'm pround of.

```
<?php
# No id provided : so this is the creation of a new local group
if($id == null){

    # If the user is not a region or a national manager, throw an error
    if(!array_key_exists('region', $this->viewVars['authUser']['auth'])
        && !array_key_exists('national', $this->viewVars['authUser']['auth'])
        && !array_key_exists('dev', $this->viewVars['authUser']['auth'])) {

        throw new NotFoundException(__("Impossible de créer un groupe local (1)"));

    }

# This is an update
} else {

    # Check the local group with the region informations
    $regionID = $this->LocalGroups->find('all')
                        ->select(['region_id'])
                        ->where(['LocalGroups.id'=>$id])
                        ->first();

    # Check the id of the user through the local group table (only has one relationship)
    $userRegionID = $this->LocalGroups->find('all')
                    ->select(['LocalGroups.region_id'])
                    ->where(['id'=>$this->Auth->user()['local_group_id']])
                    ->first();

    # The region dosn't exist, throw an error
    if(!$regionID){
        throw new NotFoundException(__('Impossible de modifier ce groupe local (2)'));
    }

    # The user is a region manager nor a national manager
    if(array_key_exists('region', $this->viewVars['authUser']['auth'])
        && !array_key_exists('dev', $this->viewVars['authUser']['auth'])
        && !array_key_exists('national', $this->viewVars['authUser']['auth'])){

        # If the id of the region associated to the local group is different than the id of the region associated to the user, throw an error
        if($regionID->region->id != $userRegionID->region_id){
            throw new NotFoundException(__('Impossible de modifier ce groupe local (3)'));
        }
    }
    # If the user is a local manager he can only edit his own local group
    elseif(array_key_exists('local', $this->viewVars['authUser']['auth'])
        && !array_key_exists('dev', $this->viewVars['authUser']['auth'])
        && !array_key_exists('region', $this->viewVars['authUser']['auth'])
        && !array_key_exists('national', $this->viewVars['authUser']['auth'])){

        # Check if he owns the local group
        if($id != $this->viewVars['authUser']['local_group_id']){
            throw new NotFoundException(__('Impossible de modifier ce groupe local (4)'));
        }

    }

}
```

That is a pretty long code and I'm always very worried that I miss something or a condition, or something. Plus I have to use this code again for other pages. So I tried to create a Component with it but it was nearly impossible to do proper access to the database inside it so I had to duplicate it and I really don't like to do that.

I really need to find a good plan to structure my code. Could you help me?

Cheer,
xSPx

Comment: I'd really recommend looking into the new [authentication](https://github.com/cakephp/authentication/) and [authorization](https://github.com/cakephp/authorization/) plugins. All of this sort of permission checking is moved into policies, which are very re-usable.

Comment: Isnt that exactly what [TinyAuth](https://github.com/dereuromark/cakephp-tinyauth) does in like 3 lines of config? :)

Comment: How about giving each role a `level` field and only allow the user to edit the `/local/...` page if he is above a specific level?

Comment: Thank you very much for your help you all, I'm curently looking into the TinyAuth plugging!